# Barcode Code128-Wide To Narrow Ratio hasn't any effect

Tags: barcode

Hi I have a Barcode tool that I use it to make barcodes in my Ms Access Reports.
I have found that the "Wide To Narrow Ratio" property hasn't any effect when I use Code128 barcodes. I tried another tool and I had the same... Why?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code128 is a fixed ratio barcode; it uses bar/space widths of 1x, 2x, 3x, and 4x.  Narrow/wide bar ratios are used in symbols like code39 and code93.

A good reference for this type of information is:  http://www.barcodeisland.com/symbolgy.phtml

Comment: Going by your profile- you are affiliated with what you linked, unless you say this in your post, SO considers this a "spam" message and could get flagged for deletion as spamming a product (and yes, I get the irony in my name, but I am literally a can of spam!)

Comment: Not affiliated.  Just a good reference site I have used often.